# How to include DE Url attribute/cloumn value in the Email body in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to include DE Url attribute/cloumn value in the Emaill asset while running the journey. PFB for this attached DE.

if it's required the AMP script, kindly let me know where can we write that script

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this:

1. Use the Personalization String (e.g. `%%TimeTradeLink%%`) for the DE (if you have it in sendable DE or in connected into a Contact Builder Attribute Group)
2. Utilize AMPScript to pull the variable via Attribute Value into a variable.

> ```
> %%[
>     SET @Link = AttributeValue("TimeTradeLink")
> ]%%
>
> This is the link: %%=v(@Link)=%%
> ```

3. Use an AMPScript Lookup into the DE to get this info

> ```
> %%[
>    SET @Link = Lookup('yourDE', 'TimeTradeLink', 'yourKey', @yourKey)
> ]%%
>
> This is the link: %%=v(@Link)=%%
> ```

When declaring, you should wrap it in a RedirectTo() function, this will ensure that the link is able to be trackable for clicks in SFMC.

`This is your link: <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@Link)=%%">%%=v(@Link)=%%</a>`

Comment: Can also use the other format {{TimeTradeLink}}.  This will pull it out of the DataExtension, as well (assuming Sendable DE).

Comment: Hi Gortonington, i have added the below code snip in the email. But still not pulling the url from DE. can you please correct the below code. 
Hi %%First Name%%,

Please follow the below link.

%%[
    SET @Link = AttributeValue("TimeTradeLink")
]%%

This is your link: <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@Link)=%%">%%=v(@Link)=%%</a>